# Android Push Notifications Parameters

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So I have looked at numerous tutorials and references but can't seem to find the information I am looking for.  I am creating a server that is built for push notifications, on the GCM notifications it looks like I need 4 pieces of information.
1.Sender_ID
2.Authorization Token
3.Device REgistration ID
4. Package name.

The issue I am having is finding out where and who is supposed to acquire these items.  I know the device registration ID is from the phone, I have found references saying that both the Authrization token and the Sender_ID are the API key.  So I am guessing one of those is the key and I am missing the other piece.  Package name I have no clue on, if anyone has any input as to where I can find this info and how to retrieve it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sender ID and Authorization token are not the same thing. These terms are actually the old terms that were used in the old C2DM API. In GCM the equivalent terms are called project ID and API key.

Sender ID is the Google API project ID.

The Authorization token is the API key (which is created for the Google API project).

The sender ID is passed as a parameter to the code within the Android app that registers the app to receive Google cloud messages. When the registration is done you get the registration ID for the specific application on the specific device.

The package name is an optional parameter, so you can ignore it.

You should read the [overview here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) for more details.